# How well-known is the expression 杯弓蛇影?

Tags: vocabulary, chengyu

I like this 成语 and brought it up in a conversation, but the person I was speaking with (an expat Chinese) didn't know it. So I would like to know how well-known it is. Would a 10 year old in Beijing be likely to know it, for instance? Or, a primary school teacher, or a 20 year old science student?

Comment: I would tag this word as "not frequently used". In my region, there are some 10-year-old boy who know this well, but there are also some 20-year-old who have no idea what it means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my mind, most well-educated individuals in China know the meaning of '杯弓蛇影' ，at least they heard about it (even do not fully understand the meaning.)

'杯弓蛇影' appears in our textbook of elementary school.

Comment: alternate written form 盃弓蛇影 (same pronunciation)

Comment: I learned this idiom from my grade school text book, there's no reason for any Chinese to not know it.

Comment: From this answer and other comments I have learnt that this chengyu is not in common parlance (i.e. not frequently used), but is taught in “elementary/grade” school - as a Brit I would say primary school. I believe many chengyu are more well-known and frequently used. For instance: 爱屋及乌; 半途而废 and 走马看花 - am I right?
Maybe this deserves a separate question about the usage frequency of some sample chengyus…

Comment: @goPlayerJuggler  Yeah, as you said, `半途而废` and `走马看花` are more visible in daily life than `杯弓蛇影`, especially in the oral expressions .